# pybind11: how to package c++ and python code into a single package?

Tags: python, c++, cmake, pybind11

I am trying to package together an existing Python code and a new C++ 11 code using CMake and pybind 11. I think I am missing something simple to add into CMake scripts, but can't find it anywhere: pybind11 examples have only C++ code and none of Python, other online resources are rather convoluted and not up-to-date -- so I just can't figure out how to package functions in both languages together and make them available via Python's `import my_package` down the line... as an example, I have cloned the cmake_example from pybind11 and [added a mult function](https://github.com/seninp/cmake_example) into `cmake_example/mult.py`

```
def mult(a, b):
    return a * b
```

how would I make it visible along with `add` and `subtract` to pass the test below?

```
import cmake_example as m

assert m.__version__ == '0.0.1'
assert m.add(1, 2) == 3
assert m.subtract(1, 2) == -1
assert m.mult(2, 2) == 4
```

currently, this test [fails..](https://travis-ci.org/seninp/cmake_example/jobs/311687281)

Thanks!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The simplest solution has nothing to do with *pybind11* as such. What authors usually do when they want to combine pure Python and C/Cython/other native extensions in the same package, is the following.

You create two modules.

1. `mymodule` is a public interface, a pure Python module
2. `_mymodule` is a private implementation, a complied module

Then in `mymodule` you import necessary symbols from `_mymoudle` (and fallback to pure Python version if necessary).

Here's example from [yarl](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/yarl) package:

1. [quoting.py](https://github.com/aio-libs/yarl/blob/2bdb8bc/yarl/quoting.py#L163)

   ```
   try:
       from ._quoting import _quote, _unquote
       quote = _quote
       unquote = _unquote
   except ImportError:  # pragma: no cover
       quote = _py_quote
       unquote = _py_unquote
   ```
2. [_quoting.pyx](https://github.com/aio-libs/yarl/blob/master/yarl/_quoting.pyx)

## Update

Here follows the script. For the sake of reproducibility I'm doing it against original [cmake_example](https://github.com/pybind/cmake_example).

```
git clone --recursive https://github.com/pybind/cmake_example.git
# at the time of writing https://github.com/pybind/cmake_example/commit/8818f493  
cd cmake_example
```

Now create pure Python modules (inside `cmake_example/cmake_example`).

`cmake_example/__init__.py`

```
"""Root module of your package"""
```

`cmake_example/math.py`

```
def mul(a, b):
    """Pure Python-only function"""
    return a * b


def add(a, b):
    """Fallback function"""    
    return a + b    

try:
    from ._math import add
except ImportError:
    pass
```

Now let's modify existing files to turn `cmake_example` module into `cmake_example._math`.

`src/main.cpp` (`subtract` removed for brevity)

```
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>

int add(int i, int j) {
    return i + j;
}

namespace py = pybind11;

PYBIND11_MODULE(_math, m) {
    m.doc() = R"pbdoc(
        Pybind11 example plugin
        -----------------------

        .. currentmodule:: _math

        .. autosummary::
           :toctree: _generate

           add
    )pbdoc";

    m.def("add", &add, R"pbdoc(
        Add two numbers

        Some other explanation about the add function.
    )pbdoc");

#ifdef VERSION_INFO
    m.attr("__version__") = VERSION_INFO;
#else
    m.attr("__version__") = "dev";
#endif
}
```

`CMakeLists.txt`

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.12)
project(cmake_example)

add_subdirectory(pybind11)
pybind11_add_module(_math src/main.cpp)
```

`setup.py`

```
# the above stays intact

from subprocess import CalledProcessError

kwargs = dict(
    name='cmake_example',
    version='0.0.1',
    author='Dean Moldovan',
    author_email='dean0x7d@gmail.com',
    description='A test project using pybind11 and CMake',
    long_description='',
    ext_modules=[CMakeExtension('cmake_example._math')],
    cmdclass=dict(build_ext=CMakeBuild),
    zip_safe=False,
    packages=['cmake_example']
)

# likely there are more exceptions, take a look at yarl example
try:
    setup(**kwargs)        
except CalledProcessError:
    print('Failed to build extension!')
    del kwargs['ext_modules']
    setup(**kwargs)
```

Now we can build it.

```
python setup.py bdist_wheel
```

In my case it produces `dist/cmake_example-0.0.1-cp27-cp27mu-linux_x86_64.whl` (if C++ compilation fails it's `cmake_example-0.0.1-py2-none-any.whl`). Here is what it contents (`unzip -l ...`):

```
Archive:  cmake_example-0.0.1-cp27-cp27mu-linux_x86_64.whl
  Length      Date    Time    Name
---------  ---------- -----   ----
        0  2017-12-05 21:42   cmake_example/__init__.py
    81088  2017-12-05 21:43   cmake_example/_math.so
      223  2017-12-05 21:46   cmake_example/math.py
       10  2017-12-05 21:48   cmake_example-0.0.1.dist-info/DESCRIPTION.rst
      343  2017-12-05 21:48   cmake_example-0.0.1.dist-info/metadata.json
       14  2017-12-05 21:48   cmake_example-0.0.1.dist-info/top_level.txt
      105  2017-12-05 21:48   cmake_example-0.0.1.dist-info/WHEEL
      226  2017-12-05 21:48   cmake_example-0.0.1.dist-info/METADATA
      766  2017-12-05 21:48   cmake_example-0.0.1.dist-info/RECORD
---------                     -------
    82775                     9 files
```

Comment: thank you, this is a very useful suggestion. i am not proficient enough in python and its packaging toolkit to implement the suggested solution on my own, even for that simple example i put on the github. would you be able to help me by shaping it to have the `mult` in c++ and a fallback in python, as you have suggested? so I can use it as a starting point for building and distributing my own package? thank you!

Comment: @seninp Take a look.

Comment: I really like the way this works with keeping a separation between C++ and Python sources and the ability to test/use those independently. Also it builds and tests seamlesly on Travis and codecov is able to pull the coverage metrics. Accepting the answer -- Thank you again!

Comment: @seninp Glad it helped. Recently added `try-except` for `setup` call so pure Python fallback is actually illustrated (bdist_wheel succeeds without cmake).

Comment: @saaj I don't understand how you use the final code after you build. If you're building a library that has both Python and compiled code in a Python module as you suggest, then how do you use it? Do you have to install it first or just put the path in PYTHONPATH to use? If it needs to be installed, are both modules (the compiled and non-compiled) installed so I can import them in Python?

Comment: @aaragon You use it like a normal Python distributable package. If it's on `sys.path`, you are be able to import `mymodule`. As the answer explains, `mymodule` should try to import  `_module` and fallback to pure Python implementation if the import fails. Example with fallback when building wheels may be a little contrived. The main benefit of Python wheels is that your users don't need a compiler to properly install your package. If it failed no one will benefit from performance of `_mymodule`. Hence it's more useful for `sdist` when compilation is optional but pure Python mode is guaranteed.

Comment: @saaj thanks for your answer. In your answer, in the `try except` block in `cmake_example/math.py` I had to put `from cmake_example._math import add` to make it work, or am I doing something wrong? Also, I was wondering if you have some suggestions for when the code you're integrating this with is bigger. Today I posted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52759716/correct-setup-py-for-mixing-python-and-c) explaining the problem.

Comment: @aaragon Yes, it indicates what something is wrong. I would suggest you to first make the example from this answer work on your machine and then gradually replace it with your stuff. I've just followed the asnwer and it still works (on this machine I had to just `apt-get install cmake python3-wheel` to make `python3 setup.py bdist_wheel` work).

Comment: There seems to be a needed addition at this time : one needs to use setuptools find_packages in order to add math.py to the whl zip file : *packages=find_packages(where=".")* to be added inside setup(...).

Answer (score 2):

Once you've cloned the repo, cd to top level directory `cmake_example'

Change ./src/main.cpp to include a "mult" function:

```
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>

int add(int i, int j) {
    return i + j;
}

int mult(int i, int j) {
   return i * j;
}

namespace py = pybind11;

PYBIND11_MODULE(cmake_example, m) {
    m.doc() = R"pbdoc(
        Pybind11 example plugin
        -----------------------

        .. currentmodule:: cmake_example

        .. autosummary::
           :toctree: _generate

           add
           subtract
           mult

    )pbdoc";

    m.def("add", &add, R"pbdoc(
        Add two numbers

        Some other explanation about the add function.
    )pbdoc");

   m.def("mult", &mult, R"pbdoc(
        Multiply two numbers

        Some other explanation about the mult function.
    )pbdoc");
```

(the rest of the file is the same)

Now make it:

```
$ cmake -H. -Bbuild
$ cmake --build build -- -j3
```

The module for import will be created in the ./build directory. Go to it, then within a python shell your example should work.

For the namespace import, you could do something with `pkgutil`:

create the directory structure:

```
./my_mod
    __init__.py
    cmake_example.***.so
```

and another parallel structure

```
./extensions
    /my_mod
        __init__.py
        cmake_example_py.py
```

and place in `./my_mod/__init__.py`

```
import pkgutil
__path__ = pkgutil.extend_path(__path__, __name__)

from .cmake_example import add, subtract
from .cmake_example_py import mult
```

in `./extensions/my_mod/__init__.py`

```
from cmake_example_py import mult
```

Then append both ./my_mod and ./extensions/my_mod to your $PYTHONPATH, it just might work (it does in my example)

Comment: this would be a valid answer if I need to code `mult` in C language, but I need it to be in Python and packaged using cmake along with `add` and `subtract` written in C... thank you

Comment: Added someting addressing this using `pkgutil`. I somehow left out that part in my original post.